# Load balancing with iptables in "nth" mode

Tags: iptables

Here is my iptables script, it does not work. Port 9000 is closed, opened ports are 9001-9003. I want to balance loadage between three services located at these ports on localhost. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

start()
{
  echo -e "\e[32mStarting firewall ...\e[m"

  iptables -F

  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:9001 -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0
  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:9002 -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0
  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:9003 -m statistic --mode nth --every 1 --packet 0
}

stop()
{
  echo -e "\e[31mStoping firewall ...\e[m"

  iptables -F
}

case "$1" in
'start')
  start
  ;;
'stop')
  stop
  ;;
'restart')
  stop
  start
  ;;
*)
  echo -e "\e[36mUsage:\e[m {start|stop|restart}"
esac
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

start()
{
  echo -e "\e[32mStarting firewall ...\e[m"

  iptables -t nat -F

  iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 9000 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination :9001
  iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 9000 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination :9002
  iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 9000 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 1 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination :9003
}

stop()
{
  echo -e "\e[31mStoping firewall ...\e[m"

  iptables -t nat -F
}

case "$1" in
'start')
  start
  ;;
'stop')
  stop
  ;;
'restart')
  stop
  start
  ;;
*)
  echo -e "\e[36mUsage:\e[m {start|stop|restart}"
esac
```

Answer (score -1):

This will send one package to 9001, the next to 9002 and so on...

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:9001 -m nth --every 3 --packet 0
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:9002 -m nth --every 3 --packet 1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:9003 -m nth --every 3 --packet 2
```

You specified the mode parameter twice, -m and --mode.

Comment: `nth` is not a module. `nth` is `--mode` parameter to module `statistic`. changing `--every` and `--packet` parameters also gives nothing.

Comment: You run the client on local host, connecting to localhost?

Comment: No, from server on another side of the city.

Comment: Do you see these packages with tcpdump?